# Is it possible to programatically give a user administrator privileges in Windows?

Tags: java, windows, admin, administrator

If I have an application which is installed and runs in system context, is it possible to programatically elevate the "current user" which the application runs on, to admin privileges? And if so, what are the possible ways to do this using Java?

Comment: It will help if you explain what you mean by "system context" and how you manage to run JVM there.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: For security reasons, no.

Only an actual administrator is able to do that.

Edit: Please note that I wrote "simple answer". There are also much more complex answers to this question. At the end of the day, almost anything is possible. By circumventing all security mechanisms. If it were not possible at all, there would be no rootkits. If you describe your exact use case, you might be offered an alternative.

Comment: Can you reference to some sort of documentation that underlines your point? You know, without "evidence" it is just a claim you put up.

Comment: My answer is based on decades of experience in software development and security. If a system would allow a running program to simply upgrade a user to administrator, that would be a serious security breach by definition.

Comment: But if the application is running in system context, that means the application has the rights to make such changes, does it not? Just like an actual administrator would have the rights to make the changes. Are you 100% sure that it's not possible, I don't see where there is any breach of security to be fair...

Comment: Perhaps I was a little inaccurate with my answer. An application that runs in the user or system context is not allowed to do that just like that. After all, you don't know what's inside the application. Not even if you have developed it yourself (unless you do without any 3rd party framework and library). Privileges can be modified by manipulating protected registry values. Definitely dangerous. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Ah, alright. Thank you. I'm trying to add a feature to my application where specific users can request and be granted admin previleges for a period of time.

Comment: We have such a feature in our company. Our user accounts are managed via company LDAP and we modify the user permissions in our LDAP directory. The user has to log out and log in again for the changes to take effect.